# map function in Option in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am a bit confused by the 3rd `println` in the code below, where the output is `None`. According to my understanding :

1. `lookupPlayer(3)` will give `None` which is a sub type of `Option[Nothing]`
2. Then `map` on `None` will be called. But how does the `map` function of `None` work ?

Please help me to understand with a simple example.

```
case class Player(name: String)

def lookupPlayer(id: Int): Option[Player] = {
  if (id == 1) Some(new Player("Sean"))
  else if(id == 2) Some(new Player("Greg"))
  else None
}

def lookupScore(player: Player): Option[Int] = {
  if (player.name == "Sean") Some(1000000) else None
}

println(lookupPlayer(1).map(lookupScore))  // Some(Some(1000000))
println(lookupPlayer(2).map(lookupScore))  // Some(None)
println(lookupPlayer(3).map(lookupScore))  // None
```

Comment: As for the second point, map on None just produce None : you could look at the source code of Option.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Option.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):Option%5BB%5D):

> final def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Option[B]
>
> Returns a scala.Some containing the result of applying f to this scala.Option's value if this scala.Option is nonempty. Otherwise return None.

So - simply put, `None.map(<any function>)` returns `None`.

Comment: But how about thisscala> None.map( x => x +1)
<console>:12: error: value + is not a member of Nothing
       None.map( x => x +1)
                        ^

scala> None.map( x => 1)
res32: Option[Int] = None , here its not giving None for function x => x +1 rather giving error . Another doubt is if Nothing does not have any instance then how x is an instance of Nothing .

Comment: @PriyaranjanSwain - In your second example you're ignoring the `Nothing` in your function and returning the constant `1`. Since there are no values of type `Nothing` your function will never be executed since `None map f ` must immediately return `None` without invoking `f` (as there is no `A` value to invoke `f` with).

Comment: First - you should note the difference between _runtime_ and _compilation_ errors. Of course, `f` must _compile_ even if it will never be executed. In this case, it can't compile because + is not defined on `Any` which will be the value of the type parameter`B` if you just use `None`. However, if you use `None` as the value of an explicitly-typed `Option`, this would compile and return `None`: `val o: Option[Int] = None; o.map(_ + 1)`.

Comment: It's not inferring the type of the parameter of the parameter to None.map as Any, it's inferring Nothing. They are opposites.

Answer (score 1):

A map operation to put in a simple term means to transform something say from x1 to x2. here x1 and x1 can either be of same type as

```
scala> Some(1).map(x => x * 2)
res10: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

or it can be of different type

```
scala> Some(1).map(x => x.toString)
res11: Option[String] = Some(1)
```

But when there is nothing to transform the output of a `map` operation is nothing. so map function on None will always return None.

```
scala> None.map((x: Int) => 0)
res1: Option[Int] = None
```

This is the definition of map function in Option class. the `isEmpty` method returns true if the `Option` is `None` and hence a map on None will always return None.

```
  @inline final def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] =
    if (isEmpty) None else Some(f(this.get))
```